# SwaggerResponse isn't working with <p> tag in .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle, .net-core-2.0

I am migrating my swagger web api page from .net framework to .net core 2. In the older page, I was using SwaggerResponse with error code and as I had same status code for two errors, I was using

tag hence description of error will be displayed in two lines.
In .net core 2, it's printing

as it is and not able to parse it properly. This seems to be issue with NuGet package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.

```
[SwaggerResponse(400, typeof(string), "<p>" + WebApiErrorMessages.EmptyQueryText
                                          + "</p><p>" + WebApiErrorMessages.InvalidQuerySyntax
                                          + "</p>")]
```

Comment: If it as clear cut as you mention, there is nothing anyone can do... Report the bug on the project page

Comment: Yes I have reported there but just wanted to make sure if that kind of issue exist or not or am I the only person who is facing that issue.
I know I can raise issue there but stackoverflow has large audience and they would also love to reply/understand the issue.

Comment: Looking at the amount of responses people don't care much about this issue... I will try my best to help you... Can you take a look at the Swagger doc, there should be your description there, can you post that section of your doc?

Comment: Thank you!
Do you want me to post the screenshot of my swagger page?

Comment: Just paste the JSON section that shows the description in question

Comment: Or post a link to the swagger doc if is publicly accessible, here is mine: http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1